# Increase height of toolbar swiftui

Tags: macos, swiftui, toolbar

Is there a way to increase the height of the SwiftUI toolbar? My toolbar items are quite squished together and if I add any padding then they are cut off from the view.

What I have done is created an empty text since I just want the toolbar, I then have one ItemGroup and some other Items of the toolbar. Each Item in the group has an image on top of the text. The text is very bunched up with the picture there

Below is the code for the toolbar:

```
    Text("").toolbar{
        ToolbarItemGroup{
            Button(action: printD){
                Label{
                    Text("Current Location")
                        .font(.caption2)
                } icon: {
                    Image(systemName: "paperplane.fill")
                        .foregroundColor(.orange)
                        .scaleEffect(1.5)
                    
                }.labelStyle(VerticalLabelStyle())
            }
            Spacer()
            Button(action: printD){
                Label{
                    Text("Get Route")
                        .font(.caption2)
                } icon: {
                    Image(systemName: "car.fill")
                        .foregroundColor(.orange)
                        .scaleEffect(1.5)

                }.labelStyle(VerticalLabelStyle())
            }
            Button(action: printD){
                Label{
                    Text("Add Place")
                        .font(.caption2)
                } icon: {
                    Image(systemName: "plus")
                        .foregroundColor(.orange)
                        .scaleEffect(1.5)

                }.labelStyle(VerticalLabelStyle())
            }

            Button(action: printD){
                Label{
                    Text("Delete Place")
                        .font(.caption2)
                } icon: {
                    Image(systemName: "trash.fill")
                        .foregroundColor(.orange)
                        .scaleEffect(1.5)

                }.labelStyle(VerticalLabelStyle())
            }

            Button(action: printD){
                Label{
                    Text("Tinted Area")
                        .font(.caption2)
                } icon: {
                    Image(systemName: "square.split.bottomrightquarter")
                        .foregroundColor(.orange)
                        .scaleEffect(1.5)

                }.labelStyle(VerticalLabelStyle())
            }
            Spacer()

            Button(action: printD){
                Label{
                    Text("Zoom Map")
                        .font(.caption2)
                } icon: {
                    Image(systemName: "map.fill")
                        .foregroundColor(.orange)
                        .scaleEffect(1.5)

                }.labelStyle(VerticalLabelStyle())
            }
            Spacer()
            Button(action: printD){
                Label{
                    Text("Share Actions")
                        .font(.caption2)
                } icon: {
                    Image(systemName: "arrowshape.turn.up.right.fill")
                        .foregroundColor(.orange)
                        .scaleEffect(1.5)

                }.labelStyle(VerticalLabelStyle())
            }
        }
        ToolbarItem{
            Menu {
                Button {
                    
                } label: {
                    Text("Linear")
                    Image(systemName: "arrow.down.right.circle")
                }
                Button {
                    
                } label: {
                    Text("Radial")
                    Image(systemName: "arrow.up.and.down.circle")
                }
            } label: {
                 Text("Style")
                 Image(systemName: "tag.circle")
            }
        }
        ToolbarItem {
            Text("").searchable(text: $searchText)
        }
    }.frame(height: 0)
```

[Photo of toolbar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yDKRh.png)

Comment: Does this help with your situation? https://stackoverflow.com/a/62867358/12053724